# How do I know my email open rate?

Tags: email, marketing

I saw some people saying their newsletter has X open-rate. How can I know this thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The technique used to work out if an email has been opened or not is to put a tracker image with a unique identifier  in the request URL so your server can log that the email has been at least viewed. This image is normally just a 1x1px square that is invisible to the end user. The src of the image will be something like `tracker.php?user_id=1312`, then on your server, `tracker.php` takes that user_id string and can mark that user as opening that email.

However, any figure you gain from from technique can't be taken expclicitly, there are a number of factors that can lead to both an over-estimate and under-underestimate:

- Most email clients ask you to download images purely for this reason
- Users may open the email but not read it
- Users may not receive the HTML version
- Images may be pre-fetched by virus scanners and scanned

Comment: This technique is also called **webbug**, and is used a lot by spammers to harvest email addresses, that's why most email clients block this images.

Comment: It won't *harvest* email addresses, but it will *validate* that an existing email address receives email.  Email clients block images to prevent spammers from validating email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Google Analytics? Then you can use http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033863 custom campaigns. Here you have an http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867 URL Builder.

Comment: The information presented at these links seem to track users who have specifically clicked on a link within an email. Can this technique be used to determine how many users actually opened the email to begin with?

Comment: Sorry. If you only want to know who opened it then no.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you distribute your newsletters, are you using client software or an online service provided by your hosting provider like phplist, or a service such as mailchimp which offer stats like open rates as standard.

the image tracker solution already mentioned is a preferred solution of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/).

- Nice UI/UX
- Pretty good stats for open rate, Clicks, unsibscribe etc
- You can also link it up to google.
- And it is **FREE**

Have been using it for the last 6 months. Only complaint is that the template editor is a bit tricky at the start.